# Silverlight control InitializeComponent freezes application

Tags: multithreading, silverlight

I have a control that I create hundreds of times during the application.
I have noticed that my app freezes because in the Initializecomponent function, 
there is
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(this, new System.Uri("/fa;component/Controls/Common/Popup/PopupItem.xaml", System.UriKind.Relative));

if I comment this out, the application runs smoothly (of course without the control rendered).

How can I avoid/increase performance so the XAML won't be loaded each time, but somehow to recycle the control??

```
for (int i = 5; i < colValues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (colValues[i].Count == "1")
                    continue;

                PopupItem pi = new PopupItem(colValues[i], false, this, FilterCategorySearch.PopupContent);
                FilterCategorySearch.PopupContent.spItemsContainer.Children.Add(pi);
            }
```

and the XAML is

```
<UserControl x:Class="FacetedSearch.Controls.Common.Popup.PopupItem"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FacetedSearch.Controls.Common"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextNormalBrush" Color="#FF656565"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextHoverBrush" Color="#FFA39F9F"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel MouseEnter="LayoutRoot_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="LayoutRoot_MouseLeave" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,4,0,0">
    <local:CTLCheckBox x:Name="cbFilter" MouseLeftButtonUp="cbFilter_MouseLeftButtonUp" Cursor="Hand" Height="14" Width="10" Margin="4,0" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbFilterName"  Foreground="{StaticResource TextNormalBrush}" MouseLeftButtonUp="tbFilterName_MouseLeftButtonUp" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="0,0,4,0" Cursor="Hand"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbFilterCount" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Foreground="{StaticResource TextNormalBrush}" FontFamily="Arial"/>
</StackPanel>
```

thanks

Comment: Could you perhaps specify a bit more about your control, and how you use it? When you say that you 'create' your control 'hundreds of times during the application', do you mean that it is a UserControl, which you use hundreds of times in your xaml? Or is a MessageBox/ChildWindow type of control, which you use to display messages to the user at runtime?

Comment: Can you explain what is in the popup you are reusing so often? There is a tendency in examples to put everthing inline in Xaml which can bloat them, when an "insert on demand" of a single shared control might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

The xaml for UserControls is parsed by Silverlight for every new instance of the UserControl. This means that if you add 100 instances of the same UserControl, the xaml will be read, parsed, instantiated as objects then visual objects 100 times.
You have 2 possibilities:

1. Access your UserControl from another location by referencing it from within a DataTemplate (used by means of, say, a ContentControl)
2. Rewrite your UserControl to be a "real" control (i.e. a sublass of Control or ContentControl)